# Question about Brouwer's Fixed point proof

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

Let $f$ a retraction from $\overline{B}^m$ to $S^{m-1}$of class $C^1$ .For all
$t\in(0,1)$  we put: $$\bigtriangledown f_t=(1-t)I+t\bigtriangledown f$$
And : $$v(t)=\int_{B^m}det \bigtriangledown f_t(x)dx $$

why the degree of th polynom $V$ is smaller than $m$ in the $t$  ?

Thank you .

Comment: have you understood why the degree is less or equal to $m$?

Comment: it was my question

Comment: $\leq$ is not the same as $<$, you said "smaller". please edit your question to clarify

Answer (score 0):

first, note that $\nabla f_t$ is affine linear in $t$.

It is also known that the determinant of a matrix of size $m\times m$ is a polynomial of the components with degree $m$.

So $\det\nabla f_t$ is a polynomial in $t$ with degree $\leq m$ (that also depends on $x$).

integrating over a domain does not change this, since $x$ is the integration variable.